# Add to cart is not visible in product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates

Anybody know how to make the "add to cart" visible on product page?
I did an update of content-product.php and after that the add to cart and choose style options are gone.
Please check the link below:

https://twinklebelle.com/product-category/rain-gear/rain-pants/

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided was a category page.

When I went to a [product page](https://twinklebelle.com/product/water-proof-fleece-lined-kids-pants-rain-pants-the-rockies/), the add to cart and options were visible.

Answer (score 0):

Please find this CSS file https://twinklebelle.com/wp-content/themes/customizr-child/style.css?ver=4.1.30

and find this css code `.woocommerce .products .product_type_variable` and replace this correct css code into css file

```
.woocommerce .products .product_type_variable {
    display: block;
}
```